# Overriding thanks command in IEEETran document

Tags: ieeetran

I am beginner at TeX and my goal is simply to add thanks text to the lower left corner. Also, I **don't** want any marker. For article document my code (below) works well. However when I change document class to IEEEtran the line above thanks text is removed. How can I add horizontal line as expected while using IEEETran.

Edit: I used an indirect solution. Line can be inserted by changing the line as,

> \author{Author Name\thanks{`\hrule\vspace{2mm}`Thanks to text}}

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts 

\makeatletter
\def\thanks#1{\protected@xdef\@thanks{\@thanks
        \protect\footnotetext{#1}}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\title{Title}

\author{Author Name\thanks{Thanks to text}}
\maketitle
\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\IEEEPARstart{T}{}he \lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you are using the `IEEEtran` class in order to submit your document to an IEEE sponsored conference, you should not tamper with the class and try to modify the commands they redefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `IEEEtran` class you can redefine `\footnoterule`. The following code show how `\footnoterule` command work when `compsoc` option is used.

```
\def\footnoterule{\relax\if@IEEEenableoneshotfootnoterule
\kern-5pt
\hbox to \columnwidth{\hfill\vrule width 0.5\columnwidth height 0.4pt\hfill}
\kern4.6pt
\global\@IEEEenableoneshotfootnoterulefalse
\else
\relax
\fi}
```

This code can be adapted for your needs as follows:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\relax\kern-5pt
\hrule
\kern4.6pt}
\makeatother
```

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts 

\makeatletter
\def\thanks#1{\protected@xdef\@thanks{\@thanks
        \protect\footnotetext{#1}}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\relax\kern-5pt
\hrule
\kern4.6pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{Title}

\author{Author Name\thanks{Thanks to text}}
\maketitle
\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\IEEEPARstart{T}{}he \lipsum[1-7]

\end{document}
```

[image]